# searchBarSearchButtonClicked of UISearchBar does not cancel the input mode

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

This code works

```
 public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
print("search")
}
```

But if keyboard search button is pressed the UISearchBar is still active. To deactivate I have to press 'cancel' button.
What have I missed?

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following solves this issue in Swift 4

`self.searchController?.isActive = false`